# Issue on charging current while switching two power sources

Tags: power-supply, diodes, switching, hardware

[image]

The circuit is to switch the voltage for battery charging circuit and not allow the solar power to 'other load' circuitry.

1. The charge current is set to 1A where in this configuration it draws only 125mA. The diodes D1, D2, D3 are SS34A.
2. When removed D2 and applied supply voltage to solar source it works fine.
3. When I replace all the diodes to 1N4004, the circuit draw sufficient charge current.

As I have tried this simulation using SS34A and 1N4004, I get no issues but practically for which property of SS34A I'm getting the problem.

Comment: What is D3 intended to do and, is there any connection between "other" and "charger"?

Comment: And your statement "the charge current is set to 1A, it draws only 125 mA" is self-contradicting. Either it's set to 1 A, or it's 125 mA.

Comment: @Andyaka D3 is for the other circuitry to protect against reverse polarity.

Comment: @MarcusMüller When I remove D2 it draws the charge current(1A) which I have set.

Comment: OK, so what is your solar cell? What voltage does it provide under load?

Comment: I have not yet implemented the solar cell. For testing purpose I'm applying DC supply of 12v, 2A to that port.

Comment: @MarcusMüller For the time being, let us consider Solar as a higher potential and DC as a lower potential.

Comment: yeah, but the current being drawn from a source depends on the source, so our "modeling" takes us nowhere here.

Comment: The source I'm using is of 12, 2A. what are probabilities ? there will not be any higher leakage because schottky dodes having less leakage current than rectifier didoes. @MarcusMüller

Comment: I assumed that component may be faulty but after replacing the diodes I found the same issue.